# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - insert datetimepicker.value in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

```
String insertUser = "Insert into 
Users(FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,Password,BirthDate,PhoneNumber)" 
+ "values('@first','@last','@ema','@pass','@bid','@num');";
 SqlCommand addUser = new SqlCommand(insertUser,scn);
addUser.Parameters.Clear();
addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", FirstNameTextbox.Text);
addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", LastNameTextbox.Text);
addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ema", EmailTextbox.Text);
addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", PasswordTextbox.Text);
addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", BirthDateDateTimePicker.Value);
addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", PhoneNumberTextbox.Text);
addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When i execute this i get the exception in the title . How can it be fixed ?

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: what should i use instead ?

Comment: Did you read the article? It explains

Comment: i am readying it now . thanks for the answer . i'm new here so i'm a bit unfamiliar with everything

Comment: Also, you appear to be wrapping your parameters in single quotes; don't. Pass them as the correct data type (using `Parameters.Add`) and remove the single quotes around them.

Comment: Whats the exception and what data type is the BirthDate column?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to insert datetimepicker.value into database.

I recommend that you remove single quotes for insertion parameters.

Besides, you need to set the BirthDate column to date type.

Code:

```
string insertUser = "Insert into Users(FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password, BirthDate, PhoneNumber)"
     + "values(@first,@last,@ema,@pass,@bid,@num);";
            SqlCommand addUser = new SqlCommand(insertUser, scn);
            addUser.Parameters.Clear();
            addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", FirstNameTextbox.Text);
            addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", LastNameTextbox.Text);
            addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ema", EmailTextbox.Text);
            addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", PasswordTextbox.Text);
            addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", BirthDateDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));              
            addUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", PhoneNumberTextbox.Text);
            addUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully");
```

Result:
[image]